# How to kill Java LWP (Light weight process) Linux

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, lightweight-processes

Is there any way to kill LWP.

I have a web application and two LWP and running continuously from last 16 hours. And those process consuming lots of core because of that cpu consumption gone 100%. I wonder if i can kill this LWP without affecting running application.

Answer (score 0):

Get PID of LWP and use kill -9 command to terminate them. Before terminating them check if they are related with your application